# Python - does deepcopy() creates another copy of Class/Static variables in memory?

Tags: python, static, static-variables

This is almost a repost of another question that I made that wasn't very clear.

```
import copy

class Obj:
    a = 3

    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self.b = n

obj1 = Obj(10)

obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj1)
```

I understand that `obj1.b` and `obj2.b` are completely different instance variables. And I understand that if I do something like

```
Obj.a = 20
```

Both `obj1.a` and `obj2.a` would be 20.

Now imagine that sizeof `a` is N bits. When I do copy a of `obj1`, does the memory store another `a` in memory (wasting another N bits) for `obj2.a` or does `obj2.a` simply points for the same place in memory as `obj1.a`?

EDIT: in my program, the class variables are a Set, an int and a tuple and I want to share them across all copies without wasting memory!

Comment: Numbers are immutable, it doesn't need to make copies of them.

Comment: @Barmar maybe the question would make more sense if `a` was a `list`.

Comment: Yes, lists will be copied. That's what makes the copy "deep".

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: If you want to know if was copied just do `id(obj1.a)` and `id(obj2.a)`

Comment: @Barmar checking `id` will tell you what happened, but not whether it was accidental or by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar mentioned in the comments, Python doesn't make copies of immutable objects like numbers, so long as they don't contain mutable objects themselves. If `a` and `b` were lists, however,

```
class Obj:
    a = [0, 1, 2]

    def __init__(self, n: list):
        self.b = n

obj1 = Obj([10, 20, 30])

obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj1)
```

```
print(hex(id(obj1)), hex(id(obj1.a)), hex(id(obj1.b)))
# Output: 0x1aa036cd7c8 0x1aa03670ec8 0x1aa036eddc8
print(hex(id(obj2)), hex(id(obj2.a)), hex(id(obj2.b)))
# Output: 0x1aa036db5c8 0x1aa03670ec8 0x1aa036cf308
```

More tests:

```
obj2.a[0] = 100
print(obj1.a)
# Output: [100, 1, 2]
```

So, to answer your question:
`obj1.a` and `obj2.a` share memory. `obj1.b` and `obj2.b` don't.

Comment: I overgeneralized. Immutable objects will be copied if they contain references mutable objects. E.g. a tuple containing lists.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know how to print the adress. I'm used to C and Java so not working with pointers is strange for me